# Used a template but am getting a different result for two pages

Tags: html

I made these two pages using what I thought was the same code for the templates, but the "Brazen Racing" and copyright notice on the "Coyote Hills" is placed correctly at the bottom right of the page while the same thing ends up part way up the page on the right for the Badger Cove page.

Wondering if anyone can tell me what I did wrong here.

Coyote Hills page (where it is correct):

http://brazenracing.com/coyotehillsfaqs.html

Badger Cove page (where it is incorrect):

http://brazenracing.com/badgercovefaqs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly add this break tag with a clear float before your href for the thingie:

```
<br class="clearfloat">
<a href="http://www.brazenracing.com/"><img src="Images/brazenlogobottom.jpg" alt="BrazenLogo" width="225" height="47" class="bigpadright" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Cool!  Don't forget to mark answer correct, I'm trying to build up my score :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  I'm assuming that's just hitting the green check, which I've done.  First time using the site!